# combining vectors as column matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have 3 vectors like the following:

```
a = np.ones(20)
b = np.zeros(20)
c = np.ones(20)
```

I am trying to combine them into one matrix of dimension 20x3.

Currently I am doing:

```
n1 = np.vstack((a,b))
n2 = np.vstack((n1,c)).T
```

This works, but isn't there a way to fill matrix with arrays in column-wise fashion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this. Here are a some examples:

Using [`np.c_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
np.c_[a, b, c]
```

Using [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and [`np.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
np.dstack((a, b, c)).squeeze()
```

Using [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and transpose (similar to your method):

```
np.vstack((a,b,c)).T
```

Using [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
np.concatenate((a, b, c)).reshape((-1, 3), order='F')
```

If efficiency matters here, the last method using `np.concatenate` appears to be by far the quickest on my computer:

```
>>> %timeit np.c_[a, b, c]
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.7 us per loop

>>> %timeit np.dstack((a, b, c)).squeeze()
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.2 us per loop

>>> %timeit np.vstack((a,b,c)).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.8 us per loop

>>> %timeit np.concatenate((a, b, c)).reshape((-1, 3), order='F')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.41 us per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `column_stack`:

```
np.column_stack((a,b,c))
```

That works for stacking general 1-d arrays. In your specific case where you want a `20x3` array such that each row is `(1,0,1)`, I'd suggest:

```
np.tile([1.,0.,1.], (20,1))
```